# How do I convert an integer to a NSDecimal?

Tags: objective-c

I need to calculate for the progress bar, but it has to take a decimal. With the code I am using, I cannot change the variable type to a integer inside the class, I have to parse. I guess could parse from integer to string to integer, but that would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an `NSNumber` with `numberWithInt:`. Than use the method `decimalValue` to get the `NSDecimal`.